# UWP 3d view aerial building opacity / transparency

Tags: uwp, opacity

I am sorry, I am moving my first steps into UWP.
I am using a `MapControl` element and it works fine but I would like to change the building opacity/transparency for the Aerial 3D view.
The problem is that whan I put some `MapElement3D` on the map I would see it on the map removing the semitransparent building but preserving the 3D view on the map.

Is there any way to have a 3DMap view without the buldings like this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGDsS.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the map appearance by set the [StyleSheet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapcontrol.StyleSheet) property of the map control to any of the existing [MapStyleSheet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapstylesheet) objects, such as the `MapStyleSheet.RoadDark()` style. Besides, you can also use JSON to define custom styles and then use that JSON to create a [MapStyleSheet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapstylesheet) object. Please see the topic [Change the appearance of a map](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/display-maps#change-the-appearance-of-a-map). Meanwhile, you can use the [MapControl.DesiredPitch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapcontrol.desiredpitch#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Maps_MapControl_DesiredPitch) Property to set a value that indicates by how many degrees you want the map to be tilted. Lastly, you can use the [MapElement3D](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapelement3d) to display a 3D element on the `MapControl`.